# How to format text output in PowerApps in scientific notation?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

[image]

In the image above, I have a text label that is dependent on a radio. If a button is selected, a multiplication is done on a value from a collection, and then the output is sent to a text label.

After the multiplication, the number I have is 71015997100, but I need to display it like 7.101e+10

Can someone guide me on how to do this?

The desired output is:
7.101e+10 or 7.101E+10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like the one below to format the number in exponential notation:

```
With(
  { v: 71015997100 },
  With(
    { p10: RoundDown(Log(v),0) },
    $"{Text(v/10^p10,"0.000")}e+{p10}"))
```

If you may have values smaller than 1 (in which case you would need a negative power of 10), you can use something like the following:

```
With(
  { v:.005697 },
  With(
    { p10: RoundDown(Log(v),0) - If(v<1, 1, 0) },
    $"{Text(v/10^p10,"0.000")}e{If(v<1,"-","+")}{Abs(p10)}"))
```

Comment: What does p10 refer to?

Comment: The power of 10, used in the scientific notation. For example, 1.23e4 is the same as 1.23 * 10^4 (10 raised to the power of 4).